Rewrite git history to transform merge commits in squashed self-contained commits
I've been trying to linearize my git history to remove merge commits and replace them by commits as if one used git merge --squash when creating them.
I have tried:
git checkout main
git log --reverse | grep "^commit " > /tmp/commits
git checkout <the oldest commit>
git checkout -b new_main
cat /tmp/commits | tail -n +2 | sed "s/commit //g" | while read commit; do git checkout --force $commit -- . > /dev/null && git commit -a --reuse-message=$commit > /dev/null   ; done


However, git checkout --force $commit -- . works for everything but does not locally delete files that were deleted in $commit, so in the end, I have a resulting new_main that contains all files, even the ones that were deleted along the way, as well as both version of renamed files.
Any suggestion as to what I could use instead of git checkout --force $commit -- . to checkout the entire state of another commit, instead of just all the files that were added / modified?

Potentially related: How do I remove local (untracked) files from the current Git working tree?

I don't think that's related, I would like for git-tracked files to be deleted when using git checkout --force $commit -- . and those files don't exist in $commit.

I think there might be some confusion about what untracked files are. "those files don't exist in $commit" would mean that those files are untracked. See e.g. 2.2 Git Basics: "Remember that each file in your working directory can be in one of two states: tracked or untracked. Tracked files are files that were in the last snapshot, as well as any newly staged files...Untracked files are everything else — any files in your working directory that were not in your last snapshot and are not in your staging area"

You will have an easier time running a sequence of git commit-tree, or git read-tree && git commit

git read-tree does the trick, thank you!

Note that you can generally use git log --first-parent to view the history in a way you are trying to achieve. Some might argue that leaving the history alone is better, because then you have the option of viewing the "squashed" history, or the original history when you need more granularity. Most UI tools also offer an option to view the first parent history as well. (Whether to leave it or change it depends on why you're trying to clean it up- if you're cleaning up garbage, then proceed, but if you're cleaning up possibly useful commits, consider leaving them.)

Following the comment from LeGEC, I managed to solve the issue with:
cat /tmp/commits | tail -n +2 | sed "s/commit //g" | while read commit; do echo $commit && git read-tree $commit > /dev/null && git commit --reuse-message=$commit > /dev/null && git checkout -- . > /dev/null && git clean -f -d > /dev/null && echo "  $(git rev-parse HEAD)" > /dev/null ; done

So, git read-tree is what I was looking for, thank you!

another command to know, to restore files from another commit, is git restore. "Setting the index to the content of commit xyz" is: git restore --staged --source xyz -- ., or shorthand git restore -S -s xyz -- ..
